# Uniqueness of solution of $y' = f(x,y)$ : $|f(x,y)-f(x,z)|\leq h(x) |y-z|$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, boundary-value-problem, lipschitz-functions, initial-value-problems

> *We assume the initial value problem : $y=f'(x,y),y(0)=0,0\leq x\leq a, |y|\le b$ where $a,b >0$. We assume that the function $f(x,y)$ is continuous and :*
>   $$|f(x,y)-f(x,z)|\leq h(x) |y-z|$$
>   *where $h:(0,a]\to \mathbb R$ integratable function.*
>
> *Prove that this problem has a **unique** solution.*

**Thoughts :**

First of all, let's assume a number $0<a_1 <a $. Then, let's assume the set :

$$D=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2: 0\leq x\leq a,|y|\leq b\}$$

Despite not having a relation like $|x| \leq a$, can we say that $f(x,y)$ is continuous over $D$ which means that it has a solution in it ?

If we also do a *Mean Value Theorem* for $f(x,y)$ with respect to $y$ handling it as a single variable function over a subset of its domain, $(z,y)$ :

$$f_y(x,y)|_{y=ξ} = \frac{f(x,y) - f(x,z)}{y-z}$$

$$\Leftrightarrow $$

$$f(x,y) - f(x,z) = f_y(x,y)|_{y=ξ} \cdot (y-z)$$

Taking absolute values :

$$|f(x,y) - f(x,z)| = |f_y(x,y)|_{y=ξ}| \cdot |y-z|$$

Now, let's commute :

$$f_y(x,y)|_{y=ξ} \equiv g(x)$$

So, we get :

$$|f(x,y) - f(x,z)| = |g(x)| \cdot |y-z|$$

which has the same form as our initial given condition, but without the $\le$ sign (which means we haven't bound it). I can't seem though how to proceed from here or if I need to do something else. I also don't get where I'll be using that the function $h(x)$ is integretable.

Please, provide me some help or a thorough solution, I'll be greatly appreciating it since I am stuck on this problem for a few days.

Comment: What is $f'(x,y)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not assume that $f$ has partial derivatives. There may even not exist local Lipschitz constants, as there are unbounded integrable functions.

What you need to do is to take 2 solutions to the same initial value problem and consider the evolution of their distance. Using 
$$
y(x)=0+\int_0^xf(s,y(s))\,ds,\;and\;z(x)=0+\int_0^xf(s,z(s))\,ds,
$$
you get
$$
\|y(x)-z(x)\|\le\int_0^xh(s)\|y(s)-z(s)\|\,ds.
$$
This you can now try to solve using the Grönwall lemma or similar considerations.

---

For instance, define $H(x)=\int_0^xh(s)\,ds$ and consider $$\phi(x)=\max_{s\in[0,x]}e^{-2H(s)}|y(s)-z(s)|.$$ Then
$$
\|y(x)-z(x)\|\le\int_0^xh(s)e^{2H(s)}\phi(x)\,ds=\frac12(e^{2H(x)}-1)\phi(x)
$$
which implies
$$
ϕ(x)\le\frac12\phi(x)
$$
which is only possible for $\phi(x)=0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Elaborate please on how I can proceed.